# Catching calls to __str__ on memoryview() object

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

I'm starting to port some code from Python2.x to Python3.x, but before I make the jump I'm trying to modernise it to recent 2.7. I'm making good progress with the various tools (e.g. futurize), but one area they leave alone is the use of `buffer()`. In Python3.x `buffer()` has been removed and replaced with `memoryview()` which in general looks to be cleaner, but it's not a 1-to-1 swap.

One way in which they differ is:

```
In [1]: a = "abcdef"
In [2]: b = buffer(a)
In [3]: m = memoryview(a)
In [4]: print b, m
abcdef <memory at 0x101b600e8>
```

That is, `str(<buffer object>)` returns a byte-string containing the contents of the object, whereas memoryviews return their `repr()`. I think the new behaviour is better, but it's causing issues.

In particular I've got some code which is throwing an exception because it's receiving a byte-string containing `<memory at 0x1016c95a8>`. That suggests that there's a piece of code somewhere else that is relying on this behaviour to work, but I'm having real trouble finding it.

Does anybody have a good debugging trick for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

One possible trick is to write a subclass of the `memoryview` and temporarily change all your `memoryview` instances to, lets say, `memoryview_debug` versions:

```
class memoryview_debug(memoryview):
    def __init__(self, string):
        memoryview.__init__(self, string)

    def __str__(self):
        # ... place a breakpoint, log the call, print stack trace, etc.
        return memoryview.__str__(self)
```

**EDIT:**

As noted by OP it is apparently impossible to subclass from `memoryview`. Fortunately thanks to dynamic typing that's not a big problem in Python, it will be just more inconvenient. You can change inheritance to composition:

```
class memoryview_debug:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.innerMemoryView = memoryview(string)

    def tobytes(self):
        return self.innerMemoryView.tobytes()

    def tolist(self):
        return self.innerMemoryView.tolist()

    # some other methods if used by your code 
    # and if overridden in memoryview implementation (e.g. __len__?)

    def __str__(self):
        # ... place a breakpoint, log the call, print stack trace, etc.
        return self.innerMemoryview.__str__()
```

Comment: Certainly an option. I had tried monkey patching the memoryview class to do something similar, but being built-in it shut me down. Guess I could override `builtins.memoryview()` with this class to save changing all my code...

Comment: Ah, you can't subclass memoryview (certainly in Python 2.7): TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'memoryview' is not an acceptable base type

Comment: @PaulS That's indeed unfortunate. Depending on how `memoryview` is being used by your code it you may still be able to use this idea - check my edit.